# map caps lock key to work as shift key

Tags: x11, gnome, keyboard

My HP ZBook has a keyboard issue (colleague has the same model, same issue after ~2 years, seems really poor quality). It is that the left shift key is failing. So as a work around I would like to use the caps lock key as a replacement, for the left shift key. I'm using Debian Stretch with GNOME 3.

I looked through Tweak Tool, "Caps Lock toggles ShiftLock" is mostly what I want, but I don't want to *toggle* the state, but only hold shift as long as I hold the caps lock key. How can I map the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key to behave exactly like the <kbd>left shift</kbd> key?

---

I can run `xev` to find the key code of <kbd>caps lock</kbd> (66), but obviously it doesn't emit anything for the broken <kbd>shift</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a related question at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/2194/remap-keys-in-linux). Running `xev` gives me keycode 66 for <kbd>caps lock</kbd>, and then this works:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Shift_L'
```

Comment: xev gives Shift_L keysym for Left Shift on my system. For me `xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Shift_L'` worked.